# Check whether the browser understand javascript

Tags: javascript

I am studying javascript and in my book I have such code:

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName) {
  if(document.getElementById) {
    if(document.getElementById("some_id") 
      ...
```

It is common practice to check the browser ability to use javascript or all modern browsers can work with javascript propertly and I can omit the first two conditions?

Comment: What your check does is check for `document.getElementsByTagName`, not the availability of JavaScript as such. Why, I don't understand though - AFAIK, `...byTagName()` is part of JS since the dawn of time. Different from `...byClassName()` which is implemented only in some browsers.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this book is explaining JavaScript very well.

Comment: Here is the book http://books.google.ru/books?id=LBTQ83bAz6QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=dom+scripting+web+design+with+javascript+and+the+document+object+model&source=bl&ots=z8DUgCih2v&sig=75Qcjci0CycLNtPEtZ4sQ8zynBU&hl=ru&ei=5hnQTKjjKITtOcfQ9dUE&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Pekka - it's possible the code listed is simply testing the browser's js engine's ability to use the elements in question. I'm sure you recall the days of testing `(document.all)` for IE.

Comment: The first thing you do when picking up a book is to look at the copyright notice - 2005 in this case, which is ancient in web development terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly all modern browsers support javascript, at first thought I was wondering if maybe they were trying to account for users that may have javascript disabled, but this is obviously not the case either.  I would say the first 2 conditions are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

That code won't even get executed in a browser that doesn't support Javascript, or has it turned off. Because of that, use only

```
if(document.getElementById("some_id")) {
    // meaningful code here
}
```